# Cast bigint to long

Tags: java, database, exception, casting

I am getting data from a database. I am getting classcastexception.
In database my id is saved as BIGINT but in code(object) it is long.
Is there is any problem while casting bigint to long?

Comment: What Java API are you using to query your database ? Please provide some code.

Comment: I am using Derby database.  'List list = openIncidentDao.getAll();

   for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
    openIncident = (OpenIncident) list.get(i);

   }'

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If this is MySql, you should probably use [`java.math.BigDecimal`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html).

See the table at [Java, JDBC and MySQL Types](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/5.1/en/connector-j-reference-type-conversions.html).

[image]

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. I will try it. Can you tell me if BIGINT can cause any problem?

Answer (score 16):

have you tried casting your value to BigInteger first and then get the long value with longValue()? It should work. And aioobe is right, check for null values also.

cheers!

Comment: yes, we can use predefined function <bigintegerNumber>.longValue();

Answer (score 1):

I was getting error `java.math.BigInteger cannot be cast to java.lang.Long` because I was getting the **BigInteger** while querying using Spring Data native query, so then I've resolved using below code.

```
((BigInteger)nativeQuery.getSingleResult()).longValue()
```